# Responsive grid issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a task described here - [Flexible Grid](https://codepen.io/sublet/details/QyzObj/)

The task is about creating a 1X4 grid that changes as the window size changes.

If window size is less than 720px then it should become 2X2 grid.
If window size is less than 360px then it should become 4X1 grid.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 5px;
}

.test {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.test .test__col {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 360px) {
  .test .test__col {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 720px) {
  .test .test__col {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div class="test__col"></div>
  <div class="test__col"></div>
  <div class="test__col"></div>
  <div class="test__col"></div>
</div>
```

The code works fine as expected if I set the dimensions to 768X1024 and 360X640 in my Mozilla browser. If I change it to 320X480 it fails to load in 4X1 dimensions. I am seeing below in the output.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Change `min-width` (as of *from this size up*) to `max-width` (as of *from 0 up to this size*)

Comment: @Justinas, it is working for 320X480 but failing for 768X1024

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative using flexbox layout.

The issue is that you need to use `max` in media query and correct the order. The `360px` need to be at the end to erase the `720px` one as both are valid under `360px` (of course this is not the only way to organize the media query, but I think it's the easiest one)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 5px;
}

.test {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.test .test__col {
  flex:1;
  min-height: 100px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  .test .test__col {
    flex:0 0 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
  .test .test__col {
    flex:0 0 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div class="test__col"></div>
  <div class="test__col"></div>
  <div class="test__col"></div>
  <div class="test__col"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Afif, can you please help me in understanding how this flex is working, I tried in google but was not able to understand the concept. When to go for `flex:1` and the `flex:0 0 50%` etc

Comment: @user3181365 yes sure ... `flex:1` mean fit the available content and when you put it to all the divs then they will take the same size ... `flex:0 0 50%` is almost silimar as `width:50%`, you can try to replace it and you will see ;) .. i advice you to read this : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ it wil take you few minutes and you will understand all the flex properies ;)